# plotly treemap: how do I color each box by the content of the nested rectangles, not based on the parent.?

Tags: python, colors, plotly, treemap

I am trying to make a treemap with different levels. each level has a name. it could be that a name occurs both for a parent or for a child. for example:

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px    
df = pd.DataFrame({'Parent': ['Alba', 'John', 'John', 'Alba'],
                   'Child': ['John', 'Alba', 'Jane', 'Mark']})

# Create the treemap
fig = px.treemap(df, path=['Parent', 'Child'])
    
# Show the figure
fig.show()
```

[image]

Now it is colored based on the parent. however I want each rectangle to be colored based on the name in the specific rectangle. for example, if Alba is always blue and John is always red. I want John as a child of Alba to also be red, and Alba as a child of John to also be blue, like the parent version of John and Alba. Likewise, Mark and Jane should each get their own unique color as well.

Is this possible?

thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

Finally managed to find a solution to this problem. Since I could not find it anywhere else, I will post it here:

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px 
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'Parent': ['Alba', 'John', 'John', 'Alba'],
                   'Child': ['John', 'Alba', 'Jane', 'Mark']})

# Create the treemap
fig = px.treemap(df, path=['Parent', 'Child'])
figure_data = fig["data"][0]
#list of unique names in the dataframe
names= ['Alba', 'John', 'Mark', 'Jane']
#list of unique colors for each name
colors = ['blue', 'red', 'green', 'purple']
#change the figure data by assigning a color based on the last name in sequence
color2 = []
for i in figure_data['ids']:
    color2.append(colors[np.where(np.array(names) == i.split("/")[-1])[0][0]])
figure_data['marker']['colors'] = np.array(color2)
# Show the figure
fig.show()
```

[image]